# Is there a list of Guild Wars 2 servers?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I'm going to start downloading the game client, and before I pick up any server I want to know if there's a list of each server available so I can run CMD on Windows and and choose the one with less ping.

Thank you!

Comment: Good luck. Server load varies so wildly ping won't really be a great indicator.

Comment: The [WvWvW rankings](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/pvp/wuvwuv/Updated-World-Ratings-Dec-7) list all the servers, but a lower ping isn't necessary going to give you the best experience (i.e. lower server pop means less people around to do events, dungeons, etc)

Comment: Just fyi, I'm on Blacktide, which is a highly populated server and have very rarely had any trouble with latency

Comment: @Gwen that list doesn't have pingable addresses. It's more important how near the server to my location is. I don't mind if it's populated or not.

Comment: All servers are hosted in the same place, so again, it's kinda irrelevant.

Comment: Also, PvP Areas are hosted in different hosts than the worlds are, so your PvE/Questing Ping may be different than the sPVP/WvW one

Answer (score 2):

**Compilation of Comments:**

. Here is a [List of All Servers](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/pvp/wuvwuv/Updated-World-Ratings-Dec-7) - Posted by : @Gwen

. All servers are hosted in the same area, there's no "Geografic Factor" in this case that might affect your Ping  - @DavidYell

.  PvP Areas are hosted in different hosts than the worlds are, so your PvE/Questing Ping may be different than the sPVP/WvW one - @MarcelloLins

**Extra Information:**

Here is a [Good Article](http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/1122636-GW2-command-lines-and-selecting-servers-based-on-ping-amp-latency) that has some useful CMD Commands to determine server ping and latency time.

Once you find the IP's in use, you might want to [Traceroute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) the way to the server in order to be able to check how many "stops" is your conection doing from point to point (Your pc - > Their Server)

You might also try your "Resource Monitor":

```
Go in game. Play.
Press ALT + TAB
Press WIN + R.

Enter resmon
You can see the ressource monitor. Go to the network tab, you can see GW2.exe in TCP connections. At the right of it, you have "latency". It's your latency ;p You can get the ip from ure server too.
```

I Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can find a [list of all servers on the official wiki](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/World#List_of_worlds). This list is sorted by language, so be sure to choose one in the language that you're most comfortable with.

Keep in mind that all North American servers are located together, and all European servers are located together, so the only significant factors in response time are going to be NA vs EU and server population. Choosing a server with a lower population may give you a few milliseconds better ping, but won't have as many others to play with and may not fare as well in [WvW](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/World_versus_World).

WvW and [sPvP](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Structured_PvP) matches are also hosted on arbitrary servers, so if you're looking to minimize your ping to gain an advantage in PvP, you're out of luck.